# Issue with videos in a deployed web in AZURE

Tags: html, video, html-helper, azure-web-app-service

I'm having a problem with a deployed webapp service in AZURE, the videos contained in the web page are not working.

The message is the next one:

﻿﻿**"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."**

The HTML code is the next one:

**`<a href="images/Test.mp4" class="popup-vimeo btn-video"><i class="icon-play2"></i></a>`**

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks!

Comment: if you try to open the video in a browser using the same path as you have in the HTML does it appear? Do you have the right MIME types set for your video (see https://blogs.iis.net/richma/adding-mime-types-to-your-windows-azure-web-site )

Comment: Yes thank you! Solved with a web.config file!


<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4"/>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm"/>
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Offbeatmammal mentioned, we need to configure the MIME types in web config file before we use the specific file type in our web application. Since your video type is mp4, you need to add following configuration into < system.webServer > tag.

```
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
</staticContent>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes thank you! Solved with a web.config file!

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm"/>
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```